# Fragment shader very slow when call texture2D many time

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl

I have a fragment shader for blur skin. Input is a YUV texture (it include y texture, u texture, v texture). With frame resolution is 1280x720 run on galaxy A6, it take 80ms-120ms/frame.
I found the bottle neck at greenValue() function call. It take most of time if I call it like the following code. If I only call  `"sampleColor = greenValue(blurCoordinates[0]);\n" ...` (not `"sampleColor += greenValue(blurCoordinates[0]);\n" ...` it will very fast.

```
+ "float greenValue(vec2 coord)\n"
+ "{\n"
+ " return texture2D(y_tex, coord).r - 0.344 * (texture2D(u_tex, coord).r - 0.5) - 0.714 * (texture2D(v_tex, coord).r - 0.5);\n"
+ "}\n";
+ "// some code .... if (current pixel is skin color)" 
+ "vec2 blurCoordinates[20];\n"
+ "blurCoordinates[0] = interp_tc.xy + singleStepOffset * vec2(0.0, -10.0);\n" +
+ "blurCoordinates[1] = interp_tc.xy + singleStepOffset * vec2(0.0, 10.0);\n" +
+ "blurCoordinates[2] = interp_tc.xy + singleStepOffset * vec2(-10.0, 0.0);\n" +
+ "blurCoordinates[3] = interp_tc.xy + singleStepOffset * vec2(10.0, 0.0);\n" +
+ "blurCoordinates[4] = interp_tc.xy + singleStepOffset * vec2(5.0, -8.0);\n" +
+ "blurCoordinates[5] = interp_tc.xy + singleStepOffset * vec2(5.0, 8.0);\n" +
+ "blurCoordinates[6] = interp_tc.xy + singleStepOffset * vec2(-5.0, 8.0);\n" +
+ "blurCoordinates[7] = interp_tc.xy + singleStepOffset * vec2(-5.0, -8.0);\n" +
+ "blurCoordinates[8] = interp_tc.xy + singleStepOffset * vec2(8.0, -5.0);\n" +
+ "blurCoordinates[9] = interp_tc.xy + singleStepOffset * vec2(8.0, 5.0);\n" +
+ "blurCoordinates[10] = interp_tc.xy + singleStepOffset * vec2(-8.0, 5.0);\n" +
+ "blurCoordinates[11] = interp_tc.xy + singleStepOffset * vec2(-8.0, -5.0);\n" +
+ "blurCoordinates[12] = interp_tc.xy + singleStepOffset * vec2(0.0, -6.0);\n" +
+ "blurCoordinates[13] = interp_tc.xy + singleStepOffset * vec2(0.0, 6.0);\n" +
+ "blurCoordinates[14] = interp_tc.xy + singleStepOffset * vec2(6.0, 0.0);\n" +
+ "blurCoordinates[15] = interp_tc.xy + singleStepOffset * vec2(-6.0, 0.0);\n" +
+ "blurCoordinates[16] = interp_tc.xy + singleStepOffset * vec2(-4.0, -4.0);\n" +
+ "blurCoordinates[17] = interp_tc.xy + singleStepOffset * vec2(-4.0, 4.0);\n" +
+ "blurCoordinates[18] = interp_tc.xy + singleStepOffset * vec2(4.0, -4.0);\n" +
+ "blurCoordinates[19] = interp_tc.xy + singleStepOffset * vec2(4.0, 4.0);\n";
+ "// some code ...." 
+ "float sampleColor = centralColor.g * 20.0;\n"
+ "sampleColor += greenValue(blurCoordinates[0]);\n"
+ "sampleColor += greenValue(blurCoordinates[1]);\n"
+ "sampleColor += greenValue(blurCoordinates[2]);\n"
+ "sampleColor += greenValue(blurCoordinates[3]);\n"
+ "sampleColor += greenValue(blurCoordinates[4]);\n"
+ "sampleColor += greenValue(blurCoordinates[5]);\n"
+ "sampleColor += greenValue(blurCoordinates[6]);\n"
+ "sampleColor += greenValue(blurCoordinates[7]);\n"
+ "sampleColor += greenValue(blurCoordinates[8]);\n"
+ "sampleColor += greenValue(blurCoordinates[9]);\n"
+ "sampleColor += greenValue(blurCoordinates[10]);\n"
+ "sampleColor += greenValue(blurCoordinates[11]);\n"
+ "sampleColor += greenValue(blurCoordinates[12]) * 2.0;\n"
+ "sampleColor += greenValue(blurCoordinates[13]) * 2.0;\n"
+ "sampleColor += greenValue(blurCoordinates[14]) * 2.0;\n"
+ "sampleColor += greenValue(blurCoordinates[15]) * 2.0;\n"
+ "sampleColor += greenValue(blurCoordinates[16]) * 2.0;\n"
+ "sampleColor += greenValue(blurCoordinates[17]) * 2.0;\n"
+ "sampleColor += greenValue(blurCoordinates[18]) * 2.0;\n"
+ "sampleColor += greenValue(blurCoordinates[19]) * 2.0;\n";
```

Are there a better solution to this problem, or any way to optimize this shader?

**Update**

1. If frame resoluton is 1280x720, number of texture2D() calling = 1280x720x20x3 = 55,296,000 (calling) / frame
2. If I replace (u_tex and v_tex) by y_tex (for test), it's very fast. So, maybe access 3 difference texture make bottle neck.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing 60 texture samples per pixel on an entry level phone! Yes, it's going to be slow.

Not sure which device variant you have, but assuming it's the Mali-T830 MP1 one then you can do 1 texture sample per clock cycle. Assuming it's around 550Mhz for sake of argument and easy maths, then:

```
550M / 55M samples = 100ms / frame
```

... which is about what you are seeing. This shader is just far too complex for this device.

Flipping this around you can set a budget based on what you want to achieve. I.e. at 60 FPS

```
550M / 60 = 9.16M cycles/frame.
9.16M / (1280 * 720) = 9.95 samples per pixel.
```

For YUV data try to pull it directly from an external sampler. For this you can sample directly from the original YUV data including color conversion, on a newer device this will be much faster than hand rolling your own sampling code as most GPUs can sample YUV natively (Note - it won't help much on a Mali-T830 though).

> Are there a better solution to this problem, or any way to optimize this shader?

Learn to use a profiler - helps avoid guess work.

For Mali GPUs, see the Streamline profiler in Arm Mobile Studio (https://developer.arm.com/mobile-studio).

> If I only call  "sampleColor = greenValue(blurCoordinates[0]);\n" ... (not "sampleColor += greenValue(blurCoordinates[0]);\n" ... it will very fast.

Yes, the compiler will optimize out 19 out of the 20 samples, so you're doing 5% of the work, so would expect it to be 20x faster.

> If I replace (u_tex and v_tex) by y_tex (for test), it's very fast.

This makes the three texture operations identical, so you remove 2 out of 3 texture samples, and the compiler can merge a lot of the maths.

Comment: Thanks for fast response, I have an idea, can you please consider helping me:
1. Since blurCoordinates can overlap between pixels, can I precompute and use SSBO to store all greenValue (blurCoordinates[i]) before using this shader. Do you think this is more optimal?
2. Can I combine y_tex, u_tex, v_tex into the same texture, then sample on this texture. Would this be faster? Since I'm new in computer graphics I don't know if these solutions are possible?